# from 2D image to 3D model

Tags: camera, camera-matrix

I have a 2D image and a 3D cad model. I have camera matrix P where P=k[R -RC]. How can I recalculate the 3 D model [X Y Z ] from that view which camera sees by pixel coordinates [u v]? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't. It's not possible.

Comment: Why is not possible, We have U=PX, U pixel coord, X world coord, and then X=INV(P)U. why this doesn't work? and if not can we just have view direction and then calculate the intersection with 3D model?